# Is there any way to delete a rectangle in matlab figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I plot some data on a matlab figure. Then I draw a rectangle using the command

```
rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h])
```

The rectangle appears on the plotted matlab figure. After that I want to remove that rectangle. But I found that I cannot click on it and delete it. Deleting the figure and plotting all data again is fine to me. I just wonder if there is any way to delete just the rectangle drawn by the command above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply assign a handle to the rectangle during its creation, then you can delete it.

Example:

```
hRectangle = rectangle('Position',[x,y,w,h])
```

and to delete it:

```
delete(hRectangle)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah there is!

```
plot(1:10);
hold on
rect=rectangle('Position',[2,3,4,5]);

pause;
delete(rect);
```

Try it at home, its safe!

Search documentation for [delete()](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delete.html)